# Create Dynamic id to MenuItem programatically

Tags: android, menuitem, navigation-drawer

I am creating dynamic menu items in Navigation view with network dynamic data. I know that I can create dynamic MenuItem by both way as follow.

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().add("Menu1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_trending_down_black_24dp);
navigationView.getMenu().add("Menu2").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_trending_up_black_24dp);
```

**OR**

```
 Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
 SubMenu topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu("");
 topChannelMenu.add("Menu1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_trending_down_black_24dp);
 topChannelMenu.add("Menu2").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_trending_up_black_24dp);
```

My problem is that after creating these menu items, I wanna make an action when click one of them. So, I tried to set dynamic id for these menu, although I tried to use `setId()` method but it doesn't work with menu. So, my question is how to set ID for these menu?Any ideas or alternative are appreciating.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntaxe to dynamically add itemId

```
Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
SubMenu topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu(int groupId, 
                int itemId, 
                int order, 
                CharSequence title);
```